# Converting string to int doesn't work properly in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Converting string to int doesn't work properly in terminal.

I want to find how much time specific string occur in a big string.

```
if ((echo "iOS/i" | grep -o iOS/ | wc -l | bc)>2) then echo "ThreeOrMore"; else echo"TwoOrLess"; fi
```

result

```
ThreeOrMore
```

But the result actually should be TwoOrLess

but inner part works well

```
echo "iOS/i" | grep -o iOS | wc -l | bc
```

result

```
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `>` to compare numbers in `bash` (`>` is used to redirect output to a file), you need to run the comparison as part of a `test`/`[` command. Also the call to `bc` doesn't seem to do anything, `echo "iOS/i" | grep -o iOS | wc -l` already outputs `1`.

The updated snippet looks like this (split on several lines for easier readability):

```
if [ $(echo "iOS/i" | grep -o iOS/ | wc -l) -gt 2 ]; then
    echo "ThreeOrMore"
else
    echo "TwoOrLess"
fi
```

Comment: So | wc -l is needed. I tried to omit wc -l, but this expression didn't returned 3 : echo "iOS/iOS/iOS" | grep -o -c iOS

Comment: Ah, looks like I just learned something. Thanks, I'll edit the answer accordingly.